# Laravel Webpack - Mix file from app folder

Tags: laravel, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack with a file from a folder located on `Project/app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss` and `Project/app/Dashboard/Resources/js/main.js`, but I get an error.

I've try:

```
mix.js('app/Dashboard/Resources/js/main.js', 'public/js/dashboard.js')
   .sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css/dashboard.css');
```

-

```
mix.js('app/Dashboard/Resources/js/main.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css');
```

-

```
mix.script('app/Dashboard/Resources/js/main.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css');
```

-

```
mix.sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css');
```

-

```
mix.sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css/dashboard.css');
```

Comment: `mix.js('app/Dashboard/Resources/js/main.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('app/Dashboard/Resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css');` looks correct. Can you share error list?

Answer (score 0):

So... yes... This is awkward... In one of the .scss files, I had a link to a missing image. Check all the url, they should exist.